# How to get <ip> to show in markdown without declaring as code?

Tags: support, markdown

How do I get `<ip>` to show up in markdown without declaring it as `code`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`&lt;ip&gt;` will show <ip> but I think writing it as `code` is fine.

Comment: I was actually trying to put it in the middle of a text quote, so using `code` tags made the spacing a little odd.